# Skip image and move to the next if the src doesn't exist for an image swapping application

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an application I've built that cycles through images and some videos every 10 seconds in a controlled format. I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to skip an image in the list of images if the id provided doesn't load an image (basically the src image doesn't exist).

The images are pulled from an assets folder. I've looked into jquery .load but i'm unsure of how to wrap the entire image cycle and check if the image exists at the same time.

```
function takeover_timing() {

    // LOOP 1
    setTimeout(function() {
      $("#screen-1-image-1").addClass("active");
    }, 10000); // 10 seconds

    setTimeout(function() {
      $("#screen-1-image-1").removeClass("active");
      $("#screen-2-image-1").addClass("active");
    }, 20000); // 20 seconds

    setTimeout(function() {
      $("#screen-2-image-1").removeClass("active");
      $("#screen-3-image-1").addClass("active");
    }, 30000); // 30 seconds

    setTimeout(function() {
      $("#screen-3-image-1").removeClass("active");
      $("#screen-1-image-2").addClass("active");
    }, 40000); // 40 seconds


    // total time: 40 seconds
    // don't repeat this function until we're done with everything above
    setTimeout(takeover_timing, 40000);
  }
```

If #screen-2-image-1 doesn't have an image or video, i'd like to make it skip over to the next image in the takeover_timing function #screen-3-image-1

Comment: Hi.  Have you been able to resolve this issue?  If so, could you notify as such when you get a chance?  It'd be nice to clean this up and remove it from my attention queue.

Comment: will do, sorry for delaying on the reply, got busy :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this is rather embarrasing.  I've answered this in a number of different ways (sorry) and, *finally*, I'm going to provide the following solution, which sticks as close to the original technique as I can.  This is tested and should work:

Image code:

```
  <img id='#screen-1-image-1' src='myImage1' onError='$(this).addClass("badMedia")'>
  <img id='#screen-1-image-2' src='myImage2' onError='$(this).addClass("badMedia")'>
  <img id='#screen-1-image-3' src='myImage3' onError='$(this).addClass("badMedia")'>
  <img id='#screen-1-image-4' src='myImage4' onError='$(this).addClass("badMedia")'>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
    var priorMedia = $("#i4");
    function takeover_timing() {
        var timeout = 0;

        if (!$("#screen-1-image-1").hasClass("badMedia"))
        {
            let toDeactivate = priorMedia;
            setTimeout(function() {
                toDeactivate.removeClass("active");
                $("#screen-1-image-1").addClass("active");
            }, timeout);
            priorMedia = $("#screen-1-image-1");
            timeout += 1000;
        }

        if (!$("#screen-1-image-2").hasClass("badMedia"))
        {
            let toDeactivate = priorMedia;
            setTimeout(function() {
                toDeactivate.removeClass("active");
                $("#screen-1-image-2").addClass("active");
            }, timeout);
            priorMedia = $("#screen-1-image-2");
            timeout += 1000;
        }

        if (!$("#screen-1-image-3").hasClass("badMedia"))
        {
            let toDeactivate = priorMedia;
            setTimeout(function() {
                toDeactivate.removeClass("active");
                $("#screen-1-image-3").addClass("active");
            }, timeout);
            priorMedia = $("#screen-1-image-3");
            timeout += 1000;
        }

        if (!$("#screen-1-image-4").hasClass("badMedia"))
        {
            let toDeactivate = priorMedia;
            setTimeout(function() {
                toDeactivate.removeClass("active");
                $("#screen-1-image-4").addClass("active");
            }, timeout);
            priorMedia = $("#screen-1-image-4");
            timeout += 1000;
        }

        // don't repeat this function until we're done with everything above
        setTimeout(takeover_timing, timeout);
    }
    takeover_timing();
</script>
```

Comment: hey, so i tried this and it loads the first image but it just stays on that image even after the 10 second timeout. it doesn't remove the active class or load the next one. I've added the onError attribute to the img elements. 

Don't know if it matters but i've wrapped the entire js file in $(document).ready(function() {}

Comment: Ah, well, I see a bug: if the "#screen-2-image-1" image is bad, then the "#screen-1-image-1" image never gets deactivated.  I'll edit the code to fix this issue.

Comment: i'm also getting this console error: ReferenceError: $ is not defined[Learn More] from my index.html at line 1:1

Comment: thanks! I figured there would need to be else statements to remove the last image if the next image is bad and also to make skip to the next image in the list

Comment: The "$ is not defined" error seems to be that you are missing jquery.  This is worth looking into as a lot of your code (and, thus, my code) relies on it.

Comment: Definitely! So i was using a local jquery.min.js file, but i just used googles <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script> and the error went away! :) is this a good way to include jquery or should i go back to keeping a local min file?

Comment: That's great!  I'd say that using jquery locally vs CDN (remote hosting) depends on your situation.  In production, it's probably better to use CDN as it can be more performant (due to caching).  But if internet is not a given (such as during development) then local is better.

Comment: so i made the changes according to the edits to your code and it's still the same where it'll load the first image and won't deactivate it or activate the next one in the cycle. I've also checked if it'll load the next image if it exists and it doesn't =/

Comment: hey, so i noticed that theres a toDeactivate check in the first setTimeout when there isn't anything to deactivate. I removed it and still no change

Comment: Yeah, that line was mostly for consistency.  To be honest, I wrote this code off the top of my head and I'm not in a position to debug ATM.  I just made a small change (changed the final "screen-1-image-1" to "screen-1-image-2").  If it's still broken after that then I suggest debugging with the browsers dev tools.  Starting with seeing which elements have the "badMedia" class, then step through the code.  If you create and link to a jsfiddle then I can debug it later tonight.

Comment: so I've debugged myself for now and after you replaced the last iteration with screen-1-image-2 instead of screen-1-image-1 i noticed that the image that was showing was the screen-1-image-2 image when the first image loads in browser. It made me think that maybe it's because setTimeout needs to wrap the if statement instead of vice versa. some more editing later and i think I have it working like this :

Comment: setTimeout(function() {
    toActivate = $("#screen-1-image-1");
    if (!toActivate.hasClass("badImage")) {
      toActivate.addClass("active");
    }
  }, timeout);
  timeout += 10000;
  
  setTimeout(function() {
    toDeactivate = toActivate;
    toActivate = $("#screen-2-image-1");
    if (!toActivate.hasClass("badImage")) {
      if (toDeactivate) { toDeactivate.removeClass("active"); }
        toActivate.addClass("active");
    }
}, timeout);
    timeout += 10000;
I threw the toDeactivate = toActivate; into the beginning of the next setTimeout Function

Comment: Thanks a lot for the amazing help with this! It's really impressive that you had the logic for what i needed to do down in your head without even testing. I'm glad I was able to debug on my side too :D

Comment: Ah! but there's still an issue with if the next image to load has the "badMedia" class the image before it won't be deactivated and the image that comes after the badMedia image won't load either. I may just take you up on your offer and create a jsfiddle for you to debug it on if thats okay? :)

Comment: Sure.  Add a link to it and I'll check it out later tonight.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/zpnL90fm/1/ here you go. i tried to include everything that matters. dont mind the ff6 spritesheet images haha i just had to find some dummy images online to use. So i messed up the file path for screen-2-image-1 to show you how it runs with an image it can't load. to get the right image there just add a 6 inbetween the "//" Thanks!

Comment: Hey, is the order of the images/videos important?

Comment: Yes, they should move in a system like screen-1-image-1 to screen-2-image-1 then screen-3-image-1. If an image or video doesn't exist it should skip that one and move to the next available one in that order

Comment: Ok, I've added a completely different solution.  I ended up starting from scratch, so I hope it still works for you.  It was just getting too complex to try and massage the original technique to work right.

Comment: FYI: the reason I started from scratch is that the original technique hardcodes which images to flip on and off.  This'd be fine if that's all you need, but as soon as you want to work with "the next available image" instead of "image-x" specifically, the hardcoding becomes unwieldy.  I originally tried to use variables to work around this, but the use of "setTimeout" makes this surprisingly complicated.

Comment: Ok.  I'm really sorry for the massive changes.  I'm fairly certain that this is my final answer.  I just realized how much more complicated the prior answer probably seemed to you, so I redid it based on the original technique.  FYI: this technique has a disadvantage that the prior answer did not have in that you'll still see the bad-images at the start (until the browser determines that they are actually bad images).

Comment: hey sorry! it wasn't even you, I just got really busy with life for a bit :( i'm going to test this out tonight! then i'll mark this issue as solved! Thanks a lot man! :)

Comment: hey, so one thing that needs to be accounted for is if there is a bad image it should be skipped over without a timer delay. I'm playing these images for 10 seconds each and if the second image doesn't load for example i need it to skip to the third image right away without that 10 second timer. thanks! I tried writing and else statement that would set the timeout to +10 instead of +1000(10000 in my case) and it doesn't seem to work :/

Comment: I was mistaken, adding an else statement with a timeout += 0 does what I need it to. Thank you so much for the help, i'm marking this as the answer :)